# Trying to understand view hierarchy

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I'm writing an app with the sole purpose of trying to understand how the view hierarchy in Android works.  I am having some really harsh problems in it right now.  I'll try to be concise in my explanation here.

Setup:

Currently I have three Views.  2 are `ViewGroups` and 1 is just a `View`.  Let's say they're in this order:

```
    TestA extends ViewGroup
    TestB extends ViewGroup
    TestC extends View
    TestA->TestB->TestC
    Where TestC is in TestB and TestB is in TestA.
```

In my `Activity` I simply display the views like so:

```
TestA myView = new TestA(context);
myView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
setContentView(myView);
```

Problems:

1. The `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method of TestA is never called.  I've seen a couple solutions to this saying that my view doesn't have any dimensions (height/width = 0), however, this is not the case.  When I override `onLayout()`, I get the dimensions of my layout and they are correct.  Also, getHeight()/Width() are exactly as they should be.  I can also override `dispatchDraw()` and get my base views to draw themselves.
2. I want to animate an object in `TestB`.  Traditionally, I would override the `onDraw()` method on call `invalidate()` on itself until the object finish the animation it was supposed to do.  However, in `TestB`, when I call `invalidate()` the view never gets redrawn.  I'm under the impression that it's the job of my parent view to call the `onDraw()` method again, but my parent view does not call the `dispatchDraw()` again.

I guess my questions are, why would my `onDraw()` method of my parent view never get called to begin with?  What methods in my parent view are supposed to be called when one of it's children invalidate itself?  Is the parent the one responsible for ensure it's children get drawn or does Android take care of that?  If Android responds to `invalidate()`, why does my `TestB` never get drawn again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, after some research and a lot of trying, I've found out I was doing three things wrong in regards to problem #2.  A lot of it was simple answers but not very obvious.

- You need to override `onMeasure()` for every view.  Within `onMeasure()`, you need to call `measure()` for **every** child contained in the `ViewGroup` passing in the MeasureSpec that the child needs.
- You need to call `addView()` for **every** child you want to include.  Originally, I was simply created a view object and using it directly.  This allowed me to draw it once, but the view was not include in the view tree, thus it when I called `invalidate()` it wasn't invalidating the view tree and not redrawing.  For example:

In testA:

```
 TestB childView;
 TestA(Context context){
   ****** setup code *******
   LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   childView = new TestB(context);
   childView.setLayoutParams(params);
 }

 @Override
 protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas){
   childView.draw(canvas);
 }
```

This will draw the child view once.  However, if that view needs updating for animations or whatever, that was it.  I put `addView(childView)` in the constructor of TestA to add it to the view tree. Final code is as such:

```
 TestB childView;
 TestA(Context context){
   ****** setup code *******
   LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   childView = new TestB(context);
   childView.setLayoutParams(params);
   addView(childView);
 }

 @Override
 protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas){
   childView.draw(canvas);
 }
```

Alternatively, I could override `dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)` like so if I had many more children to draw, but I need some custom element between each drawing like grid lines or something.

```
@Override
protectd void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas){
   int childCount = getChildCount();
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       drawCustomElement();
       getChildAt(i).draw(canvas);
   }
}
```

- You must override `onLayout()` (it's abstract in `ViewGroup` anyway, so it's required anyway).  Within the this method, you must call `layout` for every child.  Even after doing the first two things, my views wouldn't invalidate.  As soon as I did this, everything worked just perfectly.

**UPDATE:**
Problem #1 has been solved.  Another extremely simply but not-so-obvious solution.

When I create an instance of `TestA`, I have to call `setWillNotDraw(false)` or else Android will not draw it for optimization reasons.  So the full setup is:

```
TestA myView = new TestA(context);
myView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
myView.setWillNotDraw(false);
setContentView(myView);
```

Comment: can you share this demo project of the Viewgroup in your blog or somewhere it will be very helpful ..Thanks mate ..

Comment: do i need to add the childView even if we specify it in XML ?

Comment: I'm sorry.  I don't have a blog or anything to upload to.  I will try to be as helpful as I can.  To answer your first question, no. When you inflate the xml, the child is contained in the `ViewGroup`. The earliest you can retrieve it is `onFinishInflate()`. After that you have a choice. Either get your children via `getChildAt(int index)` method or use `findViewById(int id)`. The index will be the order in which the children are located in xml. I don't know how the indexing works with children within children though.

Comment: @ Deev : will you be able to mail that demo ? It would be easier for me to clear my doubts with you .. I know I am asking for big share ..but it would be gr8 help !!! thanks mate

Comment: Sorry, but my demo was written in September and has long since evolved to full project.  It will take quite some time to cut it down to relevance.

Comment: ok bro, then i  guess i will clear my doubts here only as i proceed with my demo ...

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a direct answer, but [here is a fantastic tutorial](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/) on how to draw custom views and gives a great crash cours in how to animate a view. The code is very simple and clean too.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks.  This didn't solve my problems but it did help in leading to the solution.